# "Unable to resolve service for type 'Polly.IAsyncPolicy' while attempting to activate 'SqlDapperClient'."

Tags: c#, dapper, asp.net-core-3.1, polly, retry-logic

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project which is leveraging Dapper for database operations. In this case I am trying to leverage Polly to to add resiliency to the methods that are connecting to the database while fetching the data.

I referenced the below article for my POC:
https://concurrentflows.hashnode.dev/basic-dapper-resiliency-using-polly

This is my code:

```
public interface ISqlDapperClient
{
    Task<int> ExecuteAsync(string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null);
    Task<T> ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null);
    Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null);
    Task<T> QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null);
    Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>> QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn>(string sql, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn> map, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, string splitOn = "Id", int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null);
    Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>> QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TReturn>(string sql, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TReturn> map, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, string splitOn = "Id", int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null);
}

public class SqlDapperClient : ISqlDapperClient
{
    private readonly ILogger<SqlDapperClient> logger;
    private readonly string _dbConnection;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IDBAuthTokenService _dbTokenService;
    private readonly IDbConnection connection;
    private readonly IAsyncPolicy resiliencyPolicy;
    //private AsyncRetryPolicy retryPolicy;

    public SqlDapperClient(ILogger<SqlDapperClient> logger, IAsyncPolicy resiliencyPolicy, IConfiguration configuration, IDBAuthTokenService dbTokenService)
    {
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        this.resiliencyPolicy = resiliencyPolicy ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resiliencyPolicy));
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        // Read the connectionstring
        _dbConnection = _configuration[C.VaultKeys.DataDBConnString] ?? _configuration[C.AppKeys.LocalDataDBConn];
        _dbTokenService = dbTokenService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbTokenService));
        connection = OpenConnectionWithRetryAsync().Result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method that returns IDbConnection to connect with database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>IDbConnection</returns>
    private async Task<IDbConnection> OpenConnectionWithRetryAsync()
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(_dbConnection)
                       { AccessToken = await _dbTokenService.GetTokenAsync() };
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        return conn;
    }

    public Task<int> ExecuteAsync(string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null) => ExecuteWithResiliency((s, p, c) => c.ExecuteAsync(s, p, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType), sql, param);
    public Task<T> ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null) => ExecuteWithResiliency((s, p, c) => c.ExecuteScalarAsync<T>(s, p, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType), sql, param);
    public Task<T> QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null) => ExecuteWithResiliency((s, p, c) => c.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(s, p, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType), sql, param);
    public Task<IEnumerable<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string sql, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null) => ExecuteWithResiliency((s, p, c) => c.QueryAsync<T>(s, p, transaction, commandTimeout, commandType), sql, param);
    public Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>> QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn>(string sql, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TReturn> map, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, string splitOn = "Id", int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null) => ExecuteWithResiliency((s, p, c) => c.QueryAsync(s, map, p, transaction, buffered, splitOn, commandTimeout, commandType), sql, param);
    public Task<IEnumerable<TReturn>> QueryAsync<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TReturn>(string sql, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TReturn> map, object param = null, IDbTransaction transaction = null, bool buffered = true, string splitOn = "Id", int? commandTimeout = null, CommandType? commandType = null) => ExecuteWithResiliency((s, p, c) => c.QueryAsync(s, map, p, transaction, buffered, splitOn, commandTimeout, commandType), sql, param);

    private async Task<T> ExecuteWithResiliency<T>(Func<string, object, SqlConnection, Task<T>> connectionFunc, string sql, object param = null, [CallerMemberName] string operation = "")
    {
        return await resiliencyPolicy.ExecuteAsync(ctx => connectionFunc(sql, param, (SqlConnection)connection), ContextHelper.NewContext((SqlConnection)connection, logger, sql, param, operation));
    }
}
```

`SqlResiliencyPolicy`:

```
public static class SqlResiliencyPolicy
{
    private static readonly ISet<int> transientNumbers = new HashSet<int>(new[]{40613, 40197, 40501, 49918, 40549, 40550, 1205});
    private static readonly ISet<int> networkingNumbers = new HashSet<int>(new[]{258, -2, 10060, 0, 64, 26, 40, 10053});
    private static readonly ISet<int> constraintViolationNumbers = new HashSet<int>(new[]{2627, 547, 2601});

    public static IAsyncPolicy GetSqlResiliencyPolicy(TimeSpan? maxTimeout = null, int transientRetries = 3, int networkRetries = 3)
    {
        var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(maxTimeout ?? TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        var transientPolicy = Policy.Handle<SqlException>(ex => transientNumbers.Contains(ex.Number)).WaitAndRetryAsync(transientRetries, attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, attempt)), (ex, _, ctx) => ctx.GetLogger()?.LogWarning(ex, "{@Operation} Encountered Transient SqlException. Params:{@Param} Sql:{@Sql}", ctx.OperationKey, ctx[ContextHelper.ParamContextKey], ctx[ContextHelper.SqlContextKey]));
        var networkPolicy = Policy.Handle<SqlException>(ex => networkingNumbers.Contains(ex.Number)).WaitAndRetryAsync(networkRetries, attempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, attempt)), (ex, _, ctx) =>
        {
            ctx.GetLogger()?.LogWarning(ex, "{@Operation} Encountered a Network Error. Params:{@Param} Sql:{@Sql}", ctx.OperationKey, ctx[ContextHelper.ParamContextKey], ctx[ContextHelper.SqlContextKey]);
            if (ctx.TryGetConnection(out var connection))
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(connection);
        });
        var constraintPolicy = Policy.Handle<SqlException>(ex => constraintViolationNumbers.Contains(ex.Number)).CircuitBreakerAsync(1, TimeSpan.MaxValue, (ex, _, ctx) => ctx.GetLogger()?.LogError(ex, "{@Operation} Encountered a Constraint Violation. Params:{@Param} Sql:{@Sql}", ctx.OperationKey, ctx[ContextHelper.ParamContextKey], ctx[ContextHelper.SqlContextKey]), ctx =>
        {
        });
        var resiliencyPolicy = timeoutPolicy.WrapAsync(transientPolicy).WrapAsync(networkPolicy).WrapAsync(constraintPolicy);
        return resiliencyPolicy;
    }
}
```

`ContextHelper`:

```
public static class ContextHelper
{
    public static readonly string LoggerContextKey = nameof(LoggerContextKey);
    public static readonly string SqlContextKey = nameof(SqlContextKey);
    public static readonly string ParamContextKey = nameof(ParamContextKey);
    public static readonly string ConnectionContextKey = nameof(ConnectionContextKey);

    public static Polly.Context NewContext(SqlConnection connection, ILogger logger, string sql, object param, string operationKey)
    {
        return new Polly.Context(operationKey, new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {{ConnectionContextKey, connection}, {LoggerContextKey, logger}, {SqlContextKey, sql}, {ParamContextKey, param}});
    }

    public static ILogger GetLogger(this Polly.Context ctx) => ctx[LoggerContextKey] as ILogger;
    public static bool TryGetConnection(this Polly.Context ctx, out SqlConnection connection) => (connection = ctx[ConnectionContextKey] as SqlConnection) != null;
}
```

`Startup.cs` (for DI setup)

```
public static void AddSqlDapperClient(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
{
    services.AddScoped(_ => SqlResiliencyPolicy.GetSqlResiliencyPolicy());
    services.AddScoped<ISqlDapperClient, SqlDapperClient>();
}
```

On running the code at runtime I am getting an error :

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Polly.IAsyncPolicy' while attempting to activate 'SqlDapperClient'

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance?

Comment: Can we please share with us more detail about the Exception? Like which line does it throw?

Comment: What is the exact exception? Is there an inner exception with more details? It could be that `GetSqlResiliencyPolicy()` is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your service for **`IAsyncPolicy`**  with specific scope in **Startup.cs** file.

eg.

```
services.AddScoped<IAsyncPolicy, AsyncPolicy>();
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Thanks @KiranJoshi for your response. I tried to implement it but I still the same error.

Comment: @PeterCsala - Do you have further suggestions regarding it. Please help me out here.

Comment: @KiranJoshi The `IAsyncPolicy` and `ISyncPolicy` interfaces are there to define the different overloads for `Execute(Async)` and `ExecuteAndCapture(Async)` methods. The `SyncPolicy` and `AsyncPolicy` are `abstract` classes and they are serving as a base class for the concrete policies. So, your suggested registration does not make too much sense.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their response. After digging deep I figured out that it was a minor mistake from my side. I was not referencing the method: AddSqlDapperClient() in my Startup.cs class as part of DI registration process. I made the change and validated it and found working fine as expected :)

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro Please post an answer where you detail the solution. Please do not use comment for this purpose.